# Query Parameter and Category Parameter?

Tags: parameters, categories

in the example URL below, what would the QP and CP be?

http://vivisimo.com/vivisimo/cgi-bin/query-meta?radiobutton=site&v%3Aproject=vivi&query=enterprise+search&submit.x=0&submit.y=0&submit=Submit

Would QP be "query" and CP be "site"? Or, would it be "vivi&query" and "site&v%3Aproject"?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean by qp and cp, but in the above url:

query = the query string itself
v:project(encoded) = velocity project node being used

Those are the only true functional items in the url above, the others are just form inputs from buttons, etc.